# Imu values not being filtered properly

Tags: ros, imu, filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting raw data values from imu. In the raw data, orientation always remains zero (x=0, y=0, z=0, w=0) whereas angular velocity and linear acceleration keep changing their values. I have applied the imu_complimentary_filter from imu_tools ros to filter the imu data and get proper orientation values. The output data provided by complimentary filter contains non-zero values for orientation (as it should be), but the problem is that the angular velocity and linear acceleration values are not being filtered properly. For example, even when the imu is stationary, it gives varying values (basically garbage values) for angular velocity and linear acceleration as they were in the raw data. Can anyone guide me as to what should I do to filter the values of angular velocity and linear acceleration (i.e. make them zero when the robot/imu is not moving). Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233700/imu-values-not-being-filtered-properly/) by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

that is  impossible. Imu_filter is aim for calculate orientation, not filter the improper value.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0